# VB.net form reopens on its own

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2008

i have a login form, which sends u if login is correct to a main menu...the main menu has buttons leading to other forms. when clicking a button it hides the main menu and show the other form. but the problem is that when the main menu hides and other appears, the main menu reopens on its own and each time u close it, it opens again. its driving me crazy. here's the code :-

```
Public Class mainmenu

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Maintenance.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mainmenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Login.c1 <> 0 Then
            Me.memberbtn.Visible = True
        Else
            Me.memberbtn.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub memberbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles memberbtn.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Member.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

check the click events. the program doesnt give me any errors. plz help.

Comment: Does Member or Maintance form have any code that open the main menu form?

Comment: yes, each form has a back button that if pressed hides the current form and shows the main menu again. same as above.

Comment: How do you know "each time u close it, it opens again", because if it is because the code, it will show immediately after hide, human can't see it. I mean, do you have any code in 2 other forms that linked with your Main Menu form?

Comment: the button simply hides the main menu, and then shows maintenance or member form. i even deleted the back button in each form and it still pops out from nowhere. no there is no link between them with the main menu form. and about closing it, iam talking about closing it from the control box.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the wrong code.  You must have done something to ensure that the menu becomes visible again when the user closes the form.  That's the code that is causing the problem.

Let's make another version of it that doesn't have this problem.  You need to listen to the FormClosed event to know that the menu needs to become visible again.  Write a little helper method that ensures this:

```
Private Sub DisplayForm(ByVal frm As Form)
    AddHandler frm.FormClosed, AddressOf DisplayMenu
    frm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayMenu(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

A button's click event handler is now simple:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DisplayForm(New Maintenance())
End Sub
```

You can further improve the DisplayForm method.  It is very likely you'll want to set the form's StartPosition property to manual and set its Location property so that the forms show up in a consistent location on the screen.